# Does long-running queries cancel on redshift side?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

When the user executes a long-running query using SQL workbench on Redshift (uses Redshift jdbc driver) when the user cancels it, does it still keep running on Redshift? Is there any possibility that the user must manually go to Redshift and issue a `cancel <pid>` command to cancel the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be possible that some queries keep running on Redshift. You can check

#### Using Redshift Console

1. Go to your Redshift Cluster
2. Click on `Query monitoring` tab
3. There is a  `Query history` section in the `Query Monitoring` Tab
4. Then select `Queries and loads` in this section you can view the running query and also have an option to terminate it.

#### Using Redshift SQL [CANCEL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CANCEL.html)

1. First you need to find the running query Process ID (PID)

```
select pid, starttime, duration,
trim(user_name) as user,
trim (query) as querytxt
from stv_recents
where status = 'Running';
```

2. Then run `cancel #PID` command. Please replace  `#PID` with `pid` from above returned query

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes, I see that we can cancel the PID. but why do some queries (long-running mostly) keep running on Redshift even if the user did cancel it?

Comment: This could be many factor why the queries are running in the backend. One of them could be JDBC connection getting interrupted forcefully by any means network, client job cancellation etc. This only terminates the connection between the database redshift and the client application. This can't guarantee or ensure that the process/query running on redshift will also terminate. We need to implement an additional check to ensure that if the job interrupt the process running on redshift also terminates.

Comment: @Emma Can you please accept this answer if it solves your question? This will be helpful for others who have the same question.

Comment: Hello. Definitely but i’m figuring out how can i do this..as i’m new to stack overflow.

Comment: I think i just did. :) @Madiha Khalid